# Save checkbox status on every click

Tags: visualforce

I have a check box for the Account object given below in my vf page

```
<apex:outputLabel ><apex:inputField value="{!acctObj.Decline_Credit_Check__c}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Decline Credit Check </apex:outputLabel>
```

I am fairly new to salesforce and want to know how can I save and update the value of checkbox everytime it is checked or unchecked .

Answer (score 2):

You can use a commandLink to save the change. That said, I'd recommend using a wrapper class to make your life easier:

```
public class AccountWrapper {
    public class Account { get; set; }
    public void updateRecord() {
        update account;
    }
    public AccountWrapper(Account record) {
        account = record;
    }
}
```

Using a wrapper, you'd want to modify your Visualforce:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!acctObj.account.Decline_Credit_Check__c}"/>
    <apex:commandLink action="{!acctObj.updateRecord}" value="Decline Credit Check" />
```

Obviously, you'll need to modify how acctObj is being set, because it'll be a wrapper now. That'll generally look like:

```
AccountWrapper[] items = new AccountWrapper[0];
for(Account record: recordsFromQuery) {
    items.add(new AccountWrapper(record));
}
return items;
```

Alternatively, you could use an actionSupport with an onclick handler:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!acctObj.account.Decline_Credit_Check__c}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!acctObj.updateRecord}" reRender="form" />
</apex:inputField>
```

There is, of course, other ways to do this, but these are probably some of the most common ways of doing so.